# instanceof error in php wrapper class

Tags: php, oop

I started of writing a wrapper class for a pre-defined php package. Here are the classes:

```
class phpclass1
    :: ping()
    :: __construct(array $options)
    :: clear() 
    :: addDoc(phpclass2 $string)

...

class phpclass2 
    :: __construct()
    :: update()
...
```

Here are the wrapper classes that I wrote for the above 2 classes:

```
class wrapper1 {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(phpclass1 $object) {
        $this->conn = $object;
    }

    public function add(wrapper2 $document) {
        return $this->conn->addDoc($document);
    }
}

class wrapper2 extends phpclass2 {
    private $doc;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->doc = new phpclass2();
    }    
}

Here's how I'm using them:
$options = array (...);
$object = new phpclass1($options);
$conn = new wrapper1($object);
$doc = new wrapper2();
....
....
$conn->add($doc);
```

Everything was working until I used the `add` function. It gives an error: `Argument 1 passed to phpclass1::addDoc() must be an instance of phpclass2, instance of wrapper2 given`

What am I missing? I've tried out many things, but completely lost here.

Comment: The argument to `phpclass1::addDoc()` is type-hinted as a `phpclass2`, and you are passing it `$document`, which is a `wrapper2`. Unless `wrapper2` extends `phpclass2`, the type hint will fail.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I tried that, but there was some error. (I guess the php package I'm using may not entertain such duplication/cloning of instances). So I was wondering if there could be some other way.

Comment: We would need to see what the error is. As long as you don't attempt to override `final` or `private` methods, you ought to be able to extend the class save for some potentially exotic case.

Comment: If `phpclass2` is not inheriting from your `wrapper2`, that's the problem.

Comment: I don't get how you are even instantiating Wrapper1 class with '$conn = new wrapper1($options);' because it wants a phpclass1 in instantiation yet you are passing it an array

Comment: how is phpclass1 :: addDoc(phpclass2 $string) declared?

Comment: @NicholasKing: Apologies, I forgot to miss a line while posting here in SO. I've edited my code.

Comment: @ptokya that makes sense now. :-) Can you copy the definition of this method class phpclass1 :: addDoc(phpclass2 $string) into the question

Comment: @NicholasKing: `addDoc` is a function of `phpclass1`. I'm having problem with wrapping this particular function. I'm searching for the definition on php.net.

Comment: make wrapper2 $doc member public then try adding using $conn->add($doc->doc);

Comment: The only other thing you could do is combine `wrapper1` and `wrapper2` into one single class.

Comment: Biggest problem with your question (IMHO) is that you don't provide the code. Another big problem I see is that you do not clarify why in concrete you've got that question. E.g. why are you asking this? What is the concrete reason? What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: And what is the pre-defined PHP package you wrote about in the question but didn't specify further? And you might want to read about the [Proxy Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy) probably.

Comment: What are you missing? Well, you are missing `SOLID principles`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined

```
class phpclass1 :: addDoc(phpclass2 $string)
```

This method expects the argument to be an object of phpclass2, but you are passing

```
return $this->conn->addDoc($document);
```

through

```
$conn->add($doc);
```

and $doc is an object of wrapper2 not phpclass2

To fix add a new public method

```
wrapper2::getDoc()

public function add(wrapper2 $document) {
    return $this->conn->addDoc($document->getDoc());
}
```

Comment: He is correct, you are passing the wrong type, you can also solve this by making `wrapper2` extend `phpclass2`. Also see the [Proxy Pattern](http://www.mwop.net/blog/263-Proxies-in-PHP.html)

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer: I've edited my code to `extend` the `wrapper2` class to `phpclass2`. But, still it gives an error: `phpclass1::addDoc(): wrapper2 is not valid.`

Comment: You are still passing the wrong object to $this->conn->addDoc(). You are passing an object of wrapper2 instead if an object of phpclass2. Solution with adding a new public method is so simple, why won't you implement it?

Answer (score 2):

**THE PROBLEM**

You are type hinting a `wrapper1` method to accept type of `wrapper2` all well and good. Inside the `wrapper1` method you declare

```
public function add(wrapper2 $document) {
        return $this->conn->addDoc($document);
    }
```

where `$conn` is defined as a `phpclass1` instance. The problem arises as you call

```
return $this->conn->addDoc($document);
```

which is expecting a type of `phpclass2`but $document is in fact a type of `wrapper2` as we take it you cannot edit either `phpclass1` OR `phpclass2` you will need to modify your wrapper classes.

**The Solutions**

**Solution 1**

either change `wrapper2 to be`

```
class wrapper2 {
    private $doc;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->doc = new phpclass2();
    }
    public function GetDoc()
    {
      return $this->doc;
    }
}
```

and use as follows

```
$conn->add($doc->GetDoc());
```

**Solution 2**

change the signature of $doc; inside of `wrapper2` to `public` and use as follows

```
$conn->add($doc->doc);
```

for more information on typehinting in php have a look at the documentation page for it [php type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

one other thing to consider is do you need/want to type hint, not putting up an argument for/against as its already been debated at length, just a question that you may want to ask.

If the answer is yes, you may want to read the following [link](http://www.iterativethoughts.com/2012/01/type-hinting-is-bad.html) which talks about good ways and reasons to use type hinting

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, though throws an error for `destruct`: `Warning: phpclass2::__destruct():`

Comment: On a completely different note, is there any other way of implementing wrapper classes?

Comment: depending on your opinions on them you could of used interfaces in conjunction with your wrapper classes, but as far as I'm aware I would  of done much the same as what you have done. As for the destruct warning what is the complete error for it?

Comment: as has been pointed out by the other answers you could of also used inheritance by creating sub classes of `phpclass1` and `phpclass2` although that probably wouldn't make much sense in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `phpclass1::addDoc` is type hinted to take only an object of `phpclass2`.  Your `wrapper1::add` method takes an object of type `wrapper2` and then passes it to the `phpclass1::addDoc`  Based on your classes this is inconsistent as `wrapper2` is not an instance of `phpclass2`.

You need to change your typehint or allow the `wrapper2` class to provide the `phpclass2` object that it is wrapping or extending the `wrapper2` so that it is an instance of `phpclass2`

Comment: I've edited my code to `extend` the `wrapper2` class to `phpclass2`. But, still it gives an error: `phpclass1::addDoc(): wrapper2 is not valid.`

Answer (score 0):

Change `public function add(wrapper2 $document)` to `public function add($document)` the [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) is the issue.